# Square of conditional variables

Tags: conditional-expectation, conditioning

I thought that the following would hold but my classmates doubt me unfortunately:

$Z = X|Y \rightarrow Z^2 = X^2|Y$

The original problem was an expectation of this and I tried to go back to the formal definition that:

$E[X|Y] = E[X|\sigma(Y)] = \sum_i E[X|A_i] 1_{\omega \in A_i}$
where $i \neq j \rightarrow A_i \cap A_j = \emptyset$ and $\cup_{i=1}^\infty A_i = \Omega$

...and that it would not make any sense to try to square the sigma algebra or something the like so that this must be right:

$E[Z^2] = E[X^2|\sigma(Y)] = \sum_i E[X^2|A_i] 1_{\omega \in A_i} = E[X^2|Y]$

Also wrote it like this:

$E[Z^2] = \int_{-\infty}^\infty x^2 f_X(x|y)dx = E[X^2|Y]$

I also though in a more intuitive fashion that the conditioning is simply something like a parameter of a function like letting:

$f(x)|y = xy$

$f(x)^2|y = (xy)^2$

$(f(x)|y)^2 = (xy)^2$

...where $y$ can be a scalar or an other function or whatever.

Am I right or wrong and how do you reason that this is correct or wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The notation $z=x|y$ is ambiguous, so I am not quite sure if this will answer your question, but I hope it helps.

First, given some function $f[x]$ (e.g. $x^2$), we need to distinguish between its  expectation vs. its probability density. Consistency requires that the expectation should be the same whether we integrate over $x$ or $f[x]$, i.e.

$$\langle f[x]\rangle = \int f[x] \, p[x] \, dx = \int p[f] \, df$$

which means the density of $f[x]$ must satisfy

$$p[f]=p[x]\left|\frac{dx}{df}\right|$$

The point here is that if you use the first integral, $p[x]$ is always the same, needed, i.e. it does not care what the function $f$ is (only that it is deterministic).

Now for $p[x|y]$, you are correct that this can be thought of as a parameterized *family* of densities for $x$. That is, for a particular value of $y$, the conditional density $p[x|y]$ is just some fixed density function for the variable $x$.

So in the end we have
$$\langle f[x] \mid y \rangle = \int f[x] \, p[x\mid y] \, dx$$
but
$$p[f \mid y]=p[x \mid y]\left|\frac{dx}{df}\right|$$

So in terms of your original question, if you say $z=x|y$, then "$z$" is not really purely a random variable (like $x$ is), but also includes a statement about the "conditions" under which $x$ is being sampled (i.e. $y=c$ for some fixed constant $c$). Given this, the meaning of "$z^2$" seems ambiguous. The above discussion was my attempt to distinguish between the two aspects of $z=x|y$. I hope it was helpful!

Comment: Maybe it was trying to generalise the question too much, we were given that Y|X = x was Bin(n, x) and X was U(0, 1) and then asked to calculate E[Y^2]. I rewrote E[Y^2] = E[E[Y^2|X]] which i thought would be the expected value of the second moment of Bin(n, X) given x. Is this correct?

Comment: @user3685312 in general $\mathbb{E}[f[y]]=\int\mathbb{E}[\, f[y]\mid x\, ]\,p[x]\,dx$. For your particular question in the comment, I would post a new question, show what you did so far, and mark with the [self study tag](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).